# R remove spaces from custom string

Tags: string, r

I am trying to pass a list of stocks to a SQL query, sequentially. To do this, I pass a custom string to the sqlQuery command.

I build the string as follows:

```
my.stocks <- c('BIL','BTI')
a <- "SELECT TRADE_DATE_TIME,PRICE  FROM MYDATA where TRADE_DATE_TIME > '2013-01-01' and INSTR_CODE = "
b <- my.stocks[1]
c <-  "order by TRADE_DATE_TIME asc"
my.string <- paste(a,"'",b,"'",c)
```

my problem is that in the custom string, there are spaces between the quotation marks and variable b. How do I remove these spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `sep` argument to `paste`:

```
my.string <- paste(a,"'",b,"'",c, sep="")
```

You'll also have to add a space at the start of the `c` string:

```
c <-  " order by TRADE_DATE_TIME asc"
```

Comment: Or use `paste0(a, "'", b, "'", c)`